# Context returning a null value while useEffect returns object with properties

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm

Below is a component that should use `user.id` as a partition key from react context, however, when I create a new task it returned an error stating that `user/user.id` is undefined.

Please look at the code below:

```js
import React, {FC, SetStateAction, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import TButton from '../../components/button';
import Input from '../../components/input';
import {useAuth} from '../../lib/realmProvider';
import {useRealm} from '../../lib/syncProvider';
import {ITarget} from '../../lib/taskInterface';
import {Target} from '../../realm/taskSchema';
import {ObjectId} from 'bson';

const CreateTaskScreen: FC = () => {
  const [target, setTarge] = useState<Partial<ITarget>>({
    _id: '',
    _partition: user?.id!,

    description: '',
    status: false,
    createAt: new Date(Date.now()).toString(),
    updateAt: '',
  });
  const {user} = useAuth();
  const realm = useRealm();

  const targetHandler = () => {
    try {
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create<Target>('Targets', {
          _id: new ObjectId(),
          _partition: target._partition,
          description: target.description,
          status: target.status,
          createAt: target.createAt,
          updateAt: target.updateAt,
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  };

  const testHandler = () => {
    console.log(user);
  };

  const descriptionOnChange = (e: {nativeEvent: {text: SetStateAction}}) => {
    let value = e.nativeEvent.text;

    setTarge({description: value});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`from create target ${user}`);
  }, [user]);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Create a new Task</Text>
      <Input
        placeholder={'Targe Description'}
        onChange={descriptionOnChange}
        value={target.description}
        multiline={true}
      />
      <TButton title={'Add Target'} onPress={targetHandler} />
      <TButton title={'Test Button'} onPress={testHandler} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default CreateTaskScreen;
```

When the component renders`useEffect` returns `[object Object]`.
While `testHandler` returns `{}` which is empty

I really don't understand what I could be doing wrong with react context

Comment: By the time your testHandler is called, looks like the useAuth() has still not returned the user object, while your useEffect consoles user data since you have passed user in the array, which executes the code inside when user data is changed. Try to add some kind of validation before calling testHandler function, like check if user exists.

Comment: what type of function would you suggest?